# ASP.NET MVC one to one associated data is not displaying on index page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

My case is Product has one Stock. So i have added ProductId on Stocks table. Table has records like this:

**products table:**

Id | Name | Description | SellingPrice

------------------------------------------------

1  |  product1 |  desc         |  10.20

2  | product2 | prod desc    | 20.55

------------------------------------------------

**stocks table:**

Id | ProductId  | Qty

------------------------------------------------

1  | 1          | 100

2  | 2          | 250

------------------------------------------------

Now on products index page i want to display data on html table like this:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Selling Price</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>product1</td>
    <td>desc</td>
    <td>10.20</td>
    <td>100 (Note: I cannot see stock data when i open products index, this is what i want to see)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>product2</td>
    <td>product desc</td>
    <td>20.55</td>
    <td>250 (Note: I cannot see stock data when i open products index, this is what i want to see)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Below are the MVC code which i have done till now:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Decimal SellingPrice { get; set; }

    public virtual Stock Stock { get; set; }
}



 public class Stock
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}

  // GET: Products
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var products = db.Products.ToList();
        return View(products);
    }

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SellingPrice)
    </th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Stock)</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SellingPrice)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Stock.Qty)
        </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
            </tr>
}
```

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Stock.Qty This particular piece of code is not returning any record, that is why I cannot see stock data on product index page. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Here are attachment, screenshot of generated table in sql

[Products table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoFJ9.png)

[Stocks table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVLY6.png)

Comment: I think you should add `[ForeignKey("StockId")]` above `public virtual Stock Stock { get; set; }`. Take a screenshot of your generated table in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks Grandpa, let me check this way.

Comment: Make sure to regenerate your database after you add [ForeignKey] data annotation. I believe it doesn't know how to create a proper relationship because you are not following code first [conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679962(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: After i updated database it raise following error on PM console: The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Stock' on type 'IMS.Models.Product' is not valid. The foreign key name 'StockId' was not found on the dependent type 'IMS.Models.Stock'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

Comment: Also, you should add this: `public virtual int StockId { get; set; }`. [Check this out](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this on your query:

```
//Don't forget to add this on your using statements
using System.Data.Entity;

var products = db.Products.Include(x=>x.Stock).ToList();
```

You need this Include extension methods so that it will get its first level relationship with your querying table.

Update your Model as well, to include the ID of your Stock model:

```
public class Product
{
public int Id { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Description { get; set; }
public Decimal SellingPrice { get; set; }

public virtual int StockID {get;set;} //Add this
public virtual Stock Stock { get; set; }
}
```

Don't forget to update your database with your model.

Comment: Thank you Willy for quick response, i already tried this solution but not luck.

Comment: I run Update-Database command on PM after i added your code, now i am getting this error on PM, There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database. I am searching solution for this

Comment: Have you run add-migration first? @newbie

Comment: PM> Add-Migration AddForeignKeyOnProduct. Now i am getting this errors:  Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'IMS.Models.Stock' and 'IMS.Models.Product'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.